# Multiple versions of conda and pip packages

Tags: python, installation, pip, conda

Python, problem with different versions of packages.
It often happens that package developers specify obsolete versions of packages in their dependencies.

Is there a relatively simple (without editing the source code of the packages) way to specify that a particular package will have the old version of the dependency that it needs only, and not so that it is installed for the entire project. For conda and pip.

Now you have to either have several versions of the kernels, and restart all the necessary code in jupiterlab, or abandon some of the packages.

Example.
I have a skearn.

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

```
'1.1.1'
```

I want to install the auto-sklearn library.
But in https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/blob/development/requirements.txt :

```
scikit-learn>=0.24.0,<0.25.0
```

This version is obsolete, and the dependency is explicitly specified, version 1.1.1 will be overwritten by 0.25.0. I want auto-sklearn to have its old sklearn dependency.

Comment: `conda` and `pip` both have options to ignore dependency checks altogether. There is no option to simply turn it of for a single package

Comment: Ignoring dependencies is not exactly what I need. If the developer strictly specified the version of the package (for example, the one that he had), then this approach would help. But sometimes packages in new versions are backwards incompatible, and that's why the developer specifies the old version. Especially the problem arises when I myself use the new version of the package, or 2 different packages, each of which strictly specifies the version in the dependencies. I want to have both the old version and the new one, use the new one myself, the old one for the package dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to have one package reference one version of a dependency while all other packages use a different version.

Rather, use a separate environment to isolate different sets of packages that work together for different tasks.